# Java Bytecode invokeinterface instruction

Tags: java, jvm

Looking at this Java Bytecode (from the Eclipse ClassFile viewer), I noticed something strange with the `invokeinterface` instruction: It has a `nargs` (number of arguments) 'attribute' that occupies 2 bytes:

```
35  aload_2 [map]
36  ldc <String "a"> [15]
38  invokeinterface java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object) : java.lang.Object [33] [nargs: 2]
43  checkcast java.lang.String [35]
46  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.Object) : void [47]
49  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [41]
```

Why does this exist? What is the difference between `invokeinterface` and `invokevirtual`? Shouldn't the JVM be able to infer the number of arguments (thus the number of values to pop from the stack) from the given method signature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right that the number of arguments can be inferred from the signature. The [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokeinterface) has this to say about that:

"The count operand of the invokeinterface instruction records a measure of the number of argument values, where an argument value of type long or type double contributes two units to the count value and an argument of any other type contributes one unit. This information can also be derived from the descriptor of the selected method. **The redundancy is historical**."

Comment: Beat me to the punch. No idea why this was included in the first place (method descriptors existed already in the first JVM spec I'm sure?), doesn't even seem like it'd be a helpful optimization for primitive JVMs.

Comment: There's all sorts of weird and historical things hiding in the spec if you know where to look. As it happens, the vestigial fields turned out to come in handy for some of the early experiments in invokedynamic